# Must I file a tax return for my S-corp LLC?

Tags: united-states, income-tax, limited-liability-company, s-corporation

I created an LLC with S-corp election in 2018 in anticipation of doing some freelance work. In the end, I did not do the work and my LLC had no income. Am I still required to file a tax return for my LLC even though it had no income?